# Show that the restriction map from a smooth manifold to a closed submanifold is surjective

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $S \subset M$ a closed submanifold. Prove that the restriction map 
$$ r : C^\infty (M) \rightarrow C^\infty (S) \quad f \mapsto f|_S $$

This question seems very trivial, but why do we need the assumption of closedness?

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say "very trivial." You need some technical tools to start with a smooth function on $S$ and extend it to be a smooth function on $M$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. Indeed, what I thought initially is just extend some function to a larger domain. Then when I look Yang's answer I know it won't be that trivial and I need the partition of unity

Comment: You need more than that. How are you getting local extensions?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. Can you elaborate more, since what I know about partition of unity is about extend something local to global, which seems to fit in this question

Comment: Let me ask you this: I hand you a smooth function on $\Bbb R^k$ sitting inside $\Bbb R^n$ ($k<n$). How do you extend it smoothly to a function on $\Bbb R^n$? ... This is what you need to be able to do locally on your submanifold.

Comment: Prove that the restriction map what?! (is surjective)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $M = \mathbb{R}$ and $S = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Then the function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $0$ on the negative axis and $1$ on the positive axis is not in the image of the restriction map $r: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(S)$ (i.e. there is no way to smoothly (even continuously!) extend it to $\mathbb{R}$)